# Using hardware acceleration without screen/display

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, display, remote-desktop, display-manager

I have a Linux machine (ubuntu 16.04) which I want to access using remote desktop. I am currently using Teamviewer for this.

As long as the remote machine boots with a screen plugged in, this works well. However, once I boot the remote machine without a screen attached, the performance drops drastically. From Google, I learned that this the reason for this is that no hardware acceleration in used when booting without a screen.

Is there a way of convincing the remote machine to use hardware acceleration without the screen being attached on boot.

ps. The computer only has a vga port. No hdmi.